# How to capture an app start-up in a service?

Tags: c#, process, windows-services

Try to create a windows service with VS 2012. By default, there are 3 methods for the service:

```
Constructor(say MyService)
OnStart
OnStop
```

but when I put some code in Constructor, looks like it only running one time.

What I want is: when an app started from windows, for example, notepad.exe, I can capture it. 
Should I put a dead loop in the constructor to monitor process list? I thought Service should be always on like a dead loop.
So when an app start it, how to capture it in MyService?

Comment: What's "like a dead loop"? What's a "dead loop"?

Comment: I think he means a `while(true){}` loop... not sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I put a dead loop in the constructor to monitor process list?

No, that goes in `OnStart()`.  Basic pseudo-code is:

- OnStart:

  - Set up monitoring
  - Start it
- Monitoring:

  - while (true) monitor processes
  - if(stop signal) exit
- OnStop

  - Give stop signal to monitoring object

Comment: Putting an endless loop in `OnStart` is not a good idea, so *No, that goes in `OnStart`* is misleading. It is important to point out that the monitoring which is started in `OnStart` is working *asynchronously*, so that the service keeps receiving commands!

Comment: Thanks. What signal can be captured when an app starting? Where to put the monitoring? What's difference to put codes in constructor and OnStart?